# Selenium cannot load specific created profile in firefox driver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am trying to get a specific firefox profile which I created beforehand.
However when i execute the below code i get an exception saying that the profile doesn't exist.

[image]

```
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
  var profile = profileManager.GetProfile("profile");
  var options = new FirefoxOptions { Profile = profile };
  profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.profile", "profile");
  var driver = new FirefoxDriver(@"C:\Users\danza\source\repos\InstaManager\", options);
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("profile");`.

Comment: Still the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investigating this problem, I found out that it was mainly a package version issue. I was using Selenium.WebDriver alpha version nuget package. The solution was to downgrade to a stable version of this nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use it so

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile("C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profilename");
var webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(webdriverPath, options)
```

The firefox profiles are stored in the path AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles